# Accessing Class in a Breakpoint Conditional

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, xcode5

I have a method that I want to debug:

```
-(void)doAThingWithObject:(BaseDataObject *)dataObject //called VERY often
```

And I have an Xcode breakpoint inside this method which I want to only break on a certain subclass of BaseDataObject, so I add a breakpoint w/conditional to check for that class:

`[dataObject isKindOfClass:[SubClassOfBaseDataObject class]]`

However, doing so results in a parse error!

```
Stopped due to an error evaluating condition of breakpoint 11.1: "[dataObject isKindOfClass:[SubClassOfBaseDataObject class]]"
Couldn't parse conditional expression:
error: no known method '+class'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

I have made sure to import all classes in the file, but the debugger does not know what class I'm referencing in the conditional.

However, creating a temp variable of said Class inside the method before the breakpoint:

```
Class subClassCheck = [SubClassOfBaseDataObject class];
```

And updating the breakpoint conditional to reference the temp variable:

```
[dataObject isKindOfClass:subClassCheck]
```

Throws no errors.

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to breakpoint conditionals, can someone explain why my first approach doesn't work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One complication with debugging code that is based on big frameworks like Cocoa is that it is not practical for the compiler to emit or the debugger to consume every type and function in the whole closure of frameworks you include.  So the compiler uses some heuristics to reduce the amount of debug information generated.  It will emit type information only for types that you actually use, and function/ObjC method information where the method is defined (as opposed to declared in a header file.)  There's another little subtlety that lldb will read the type information for methods out of the ObjC runtime, though this information is not complete, since it is meant for the runtime not for debuggers...  So we sometimes seem to know things about ObjC methods that violate the previous rule.

Another important thing to note is that the calling conventions for functions that return something larger than a pointer (like NSMakeRect, etc) are such that if the debugger calls a function thinking it returns a pointer and it actually returns a bigger structure, that act will cause stack corruption in your program.  If you are lucky you will crash right away when you continue, but if you are unlucky it will just change some data value and cause you to spend hours trying to chase down some funny behavior that is actually caused by the debugger.  So the debugger will refuse to call functions whose return type it can't determine.

Anyway the error you got is because the debugger couldn't find debug information for the "+class" method on your object.  That is not altogether surprising, since "class" is a method on NSObject and not your class.  I'm not sure why we couldn't find it in the runtime, maybe because it is a class method?  That's worth a bug.  We obviously did get the type of isKindOfClass: from the runtime, or your workaround would have also failed.

In this case, since you actually know the return type of the class method, you can work around the debugger's lack of knowledge by explicitly casting it in your breakpoint expression.  Casting a function return in the debugger's expression parser serves two purposes, one is the regular C language function, and the other is telling the debugger the return type of a function it wouldn't otherwise be able to figure out.  A sort of short-hand prototype only for the return type.

So something like:

```
[dataObject isKindOfClass: (Class) [SubClassOfBaseDataObject class]]
```

should work without having to alter your code.

Note also, the breakpoint conditions are run using the same mechanism as the "expr" or "print" command.  So the easiest way to experiment with breakpoint commands is to set an unconditional breakpoint, hit it, then go to the lldb console and play around with "print" till you get something that works.

Comment: This is by far the most satisfying answer I've received on StackOverflow. It describes what I've found, explains the environment where I found it in, and even forewarns me with other gotchas I'll likely hit along the way when dealing with debuggers. 
 
I'm also glad my expectations are (somewhat) correct and that this is a bug-report-worthy discovery. And getting a workaround in the meantime that I can just drop in? What more could one ask for?